# How to destroy or clear Bean object state in every use in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I'm new in spring boot and trying to figure out when we create a bean using @Bean and tries to access that bean where ever it requires using @Autowired. But i know @Bean is by default singleton and it will save its state but i want to clear its state so that it will give new newly append data or null if no data was append. Kindly help me on this. And i also want to know that is i'm following correct coding standard by using Bean with autowired because i want my every api give similar type of response that's why i create a pojo and make it a bean so that i don't have to create object again and again. Sorry if my problem is silly.. thanks in advance

This is my main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class GyftiV2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GyftiV2Application.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public ResponseData getResponse() {
        return new ResponseData();
    }
}
```

Below is the pojo

```
public class ResponseData {

    private boolean responce;
    private String error;
    private List<?> data = new ArrayList<>();

    public ResponseData() {
    }

    public boolean isResponce() {
        return responce;
    }

    public void setResponce(boolean responce) {
        this.responce = responce;
    }

    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(String error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public List<?> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<?> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Below is the service where is used my bean

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

@Autowired
private ResponseData resData;

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

public ResponseData changePassword(PasswordChange pass) {
    User user = userRepository.getOne(pass.getUserId());
    if (null != user) {
        if (pass.getOldPassword().equals(user.getUser_password())) {
            if ((pass.getNewPassword().trim()).equals(pass.getConfirmPassword().trim())) {
                user.setUser_password(pass.getNewPassword());
                userRepository.save(user);
                resData.setResponce(true);
                resData.setData(Collections.singletonList("Password change successfully"));
                return resData;
            } else {
                resData.setResponce(false);
                resData.setError("Please write the same new password in the confirm section");
                return resData;
            }
        } else {
            resData.setResponce(false);
            resData.setError("Please write the correct old password");
            return resData;
        }
    } else {
        resData.setResponce(false);
        resData.setError("Something went wrong userId is not correct");
        return resData;
    }
}
```

}

With Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@PostMapping(value = "/changePassword")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseData> changePassword(@RequestBody PasswordChange pass) {
        ResponseData response = userService.changePassword(pass);
        if (response.isResponce()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

But when i didn't pass same newPassoword and confirmPassword then i got the response

```
{
  "responce": false,
  "error": "Please write the same new password in the confirm section",
  "data": []
}
```

And when i pass everything correct then i got the response

```
{
  "responce": true,
  "error": "Please write the same new password in the confirm section",
  "data": [
    "Password change successfully"
  ]
}
```

You will clearly see resData save its state that's why error key is still exist. I know if i pass "" in error field it will fix this issue but is there is any why to clear @Bean state ? Thanks for the help.

Comment: `ResponseData` shouldn't be a bean at all. It's a normal POJO. You should create one in your `changePassword` method.

Comment: So normal pojo can't be a bean ? I only declared as bean because i want to use it in every method for that i have to create ResponseData object again and again that's why i create it as a bean .. is this is a incorrect way ? What should we declare as a bean? Is there is a restriction in declaring a bean ? I'm so confused..

Comment: Yes it's an incorrect way. It shouldn't be a bean, you should create a `new ResponseData` in the method and return it. You designed your code wrong by making something a bean that doesn't make sense being a bean. You need more experience with both regular Java and Spring.

Comment: I understand i need more time with spring and java .. thanks for 
the help. Actually i have one question.. what type of object is correct for bean ? Like i saw people uses resttemplate as a bean ? Im so confused what should i create as a bean.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment, you should not be using this as a Bean... It is just a regular object.

Here is how should be your service code:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public ResponseData changePassword(PasswordChange pass) {
        User user = userRepository.getOne(pass.getUserId());
        if (null != user) {
            if (pass.getOldPassword().equals(user.getUser_password())) {
                if ((pass.getNewPassword().trim()).equals(pass.getConfirmPassword().trim())) {
                    user.setUser_password(pass.getNewPassword());
                    userRepository.save(user);
                    ResponseData resData = new ResponseData();
                    resData.setResponce(true);
                    resData.setData(Collections.singletonList("Password change successfully"));
                    return resData;
                } else {
                    ResponseData resData = new ResponseData();
                    resData.setResponce(false);
                    resData.setData("Please write the same new password in the confirm section");
                    return resData;
                }
            } else {
                ...
            }
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Things to consider:

- You shouldn't be using your service to return a ResponseDate object sent directly over to the client. Maybe use exception in your service, like `PasswordAndConfirmationAreDifferentException`. This way, it is easier to deal the way you want in your controller.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@PostMapping(value = "/changePassword")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseData> changePassword(@RequestBody PasswordChange pass) {
        try {
            userService.changePassword(pass);
            ResponseData resData = new ResponseData();
            resData.setResponce(true);
            resData.setData(Collections.singletonList("Password change successfully"));
            return new ResponseEntity<>(resData, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (PasswordAndConfirmationAreDifferentException e) {
            ResponseData resData = new ResponseData();
            resData.setResponce(false);
            resData.setData("Password incorrect");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(resData, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

- Use a builder to easily build a responseDate of type Error `ResponseData.Error("my error")` and of type Data ResponseData.Data("my message 1", "my message2", ...)

Comment: Thanks for the crystal clear explanation .. i totally understand.. a big thanks to you .. although if i want to return my object of data like full user object in the response then what is the correct way to return ? Because service class provides that object ..

Comment: Then make your service return your `User` object when things go well. Be careful with that: Do not return the `User` object containing password to the client... Protect your data. Try something out, and if you can't find a solution, make a new post.

Comment: Got it, I have to return minimal thing which is required by the client, that's why service layer should not return everything to the controller or if it returns everything we have to filters it out. I got you point .. Thanks you so much for the help I'm just practice by creating a small project by myself.. just one more thing where to use @bean means when should we go for bean  (is there is any restriction that only particular object can be declared as a bean ) ... Once again thank you so much..